# How to copy internal packed files in to a working directory in Java?

Tags: java

as you can see by the title I am trying to copy various files imported into my src to a temporary directory. In this case, there is a folder being created in the C drive called "Dank". All I wish to do is copy these internal files(http://prntscr.com/d39rmt) to the temporary folder.
Don't mind the bad body, this is just a snippet of the rest of the program which is irrelevant to this part. Thank you.
`public class sstool extends FileNotFoundException {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "unused" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path newDirectoryPath = Paths.get("C:\\Dank");
        if (!Files.exists(newDirectoryPath)) {
            try {
                Files.createDirectory(newDirectoryPath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }`

Comment: iirc, you could try `ClassLoader#getResource`, e.g. `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("cheatsmasher.exe")`, though I don't remember the iterative solution to that offhand

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but there is no way to allow Files.copy(pathfile, topathfile); with this ;/

Comment: Well you wouldn't use `Files#copy`, since `#getResource` returns a `URL`. You'd use `URL#getInputStream` and save it yourself.

Comment: Dude, I have no idea. it says URL.getInputStream is undefined for the type URL. Any other ways of doing this?

Comment: Any other methods of copying those files within the .jar?

Comment: Whoops, it's `URL#openStream` (returns an `InputStream`), my bad. You can look at the javadoc for `URL` and see the various methods.

Comment: Please do not post a link to your code;  edit your question and include your code in the question itself.  External links can move or otherwise go stale, which would make your question useless to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rogue was close.  Files embedded in your application are typically read with [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) or [Class.getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

You absolutely should use Files.copy, just not the method that takes two Path arguments:

```
String[] files = {
    "cheatsmasher.exe",
    "Everything.ini",
    "jdgui.jar",
    "launcher.jar - Shortcut.lnk",
    "LAV.cfg",
    "LAV.exe",
    "logs - Shortcut.lnk",
    "pexplorer32.exe",
    "pexplorer64.exe",
    "Prefech.lnk",
    "schem.exe",
    "SE32.exe",
    "SE64.exe",
    "skypefiles.lnk",
    "smash.dll",
    "synpase.lnk",
    "TM.lnk",
    "TS3Client.lnk",
    "USB32.cfg",
    "USB32.exe",
    "USB64.cfg",
    "USB64.exe",
    "Vape.dll",
    "vapev.jar",
    "versions - Shortcut.lnk",
};

Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Dank");
Files.createDirectories(destination);

for (String file : files) {
    try (InputStream stream =
        SSTool.class.getResourceAsStream("/tools/" + file)) {

        Files.copy(stream, destination.resolve(file));
    }
}
```

A common question on Stack Overflow is whether you can just list the contents of the directory.  The answer is: **No, you can’t.**  A .jar file is just a zip file with a different extension, and a directory in a zip file isn’t really a directory at all;  it’s just another zip entry.  (While in theory you could iterate over all of the entries looking for ones with a certain prefix, or you could even try using Java’s zip file system, those workarounds are subject to problems.)

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
 at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
 at tools.sstool.main(sstool.java:99)`

Comment: It would appear that ` sstool.class.getResourceAsStream("/tools/" + file))` is not working ;/

Comment: I was trying an extraction method, where i'd extract my own running jar to "Dank" folder and run applications off of those. But the extraction time was  in the 10minute areas.

Comment: Is the `tools` directory being packaged into your .jar?  Either use your IDE’s file window to examine the .jar file, or use your desktop to copy the file, rename the copy to have a .zip extension, and open that.

Comment: I am looking for a one file all the program thing. Lots of people are going to be downloading this, so it needs to be simple and convenient. nobody wants to put both a .jar and a tools folder on their desktop. I want the tools packaged inside the jar.

Comment: Yes using a .zip extension would work for most of the things, but cheatsmasher.exe relies on it's dll. the dll doesnt run along side the exe if it's inside a zip

Comment: You have completely misunderstood my advice.  I did not suggest that you *distribute* your program as a zip file.  I was suggesting ways you might *inspect* your own .jar file, assuming you are in fact running your program from a .jar file.  Are you running your program from a .jar file?

Comment: Yes i am. I wish to open my currently running jar file, and copying it's internals to C:\\Dank

Comment: I cannot tell you the correct value which your code should pass to `getResourceAsStream`, unless you tell me the full path in your .jar file of entries like `cheatsmasher.exe`.

Comment: Add `System.out.println(file);` at the start of the loop.  I’m curious if the first file fails, or if a later one fails.

Comment: long shot here, but try removing the first `/`

Comment: Okay, that is useful.  Now what we need to see is the exact contents of the .jar file, but not using an IDE.  Open a command window and run `jar tf C:\User\UserName\Desktop\stool.jar`.  (I assume you’ll need to replace *UserName* with your actual user name.)  You may need to place your JDK’s `bin` directory on your Path first.

Comment: Ok so I executed this command: `jar tf C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\stool.jar > C:\Users\Seth\Desktop\output.txt` Hopefully this is the output you request:http://pastebin.com/bhjfWZiB

Comment: It appears there is no file named `sstool.java` in your .jar file, so remove that name from the array.  Make sure every name in the array corresponds to a file that you are actually adding to your .jar.